# How to run all examples except one in Ruby using Rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

```
config.before(:example,) do
    visit '/'
   find('a[class=btn').click
   fill_in 'username', with: $email
   fill_in 'password', with: $password
   find('input[class=btn]').click
end
```

I want to log in to the website in all tests except one, how do i do that?

I tried this:

```
config.before(:example,) |test| do
    visit '/'
   find('a[class=btn').click
   fill_in 'username', with: $email
   fill_in 'password', with: $password
   find('input[class=btn]').click 
   unless test.metadata[:notrun]
   end
end
```

I was expecting all test run except the one with the tag :notrun, but it runs anyway

Answer (score 2):

Your `unless` block is just

unless test.metadata[:notrun]
end

so it's not doing anything.  If you wanted the code in the before to not run then you could wrap it all in the `unless`

```
config.before(:example) |test| do
  unless test.metadata[:notrun]
    visit '/'
    find('a[class=btn').click
    fill_in 'username', with: $email
    fill_in 'password', with: $password
    find('input[class=btn]').click 
  end
end
```

but that will just stop the before hook from doing anything on the tagged test(s), it won't actually prevent the test from being run. Easiest way to prevent a specific example from being run is just to tag it with `skip` (instead of your `notrun`)

```
it 'blah blah', skip: true do
  ....
end
```

Comment: [Pending and skipped examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-12/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to login before every test except one. Using `skip: true` will actually skip the test, not the `before` block.

There is a way to configure a `before` block to only execute on certain tests using metadata. It works like this:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, login: true) do
    visit '/'
    find('a[class=btn').click
    fill_in 'username', with: $email
    fill_in 'password', with: $password
    find('input[class=btn]').click 
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'MyController' do
  describe '#index' do 
    it 'does something while logged out'

    context 'logged in', login: true do
      it 'does something while logged in'
      it 'does something else while logged in'
    end
  end
end
```

You can place the metadata on any `describe`, `context`, or `example`/`it` block. So, if you had a file full of tests that should be logged in, you'd just put the metadata on the outermost `describe` at the top of the file.